# maven does not say which class fails to compile

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to compile my project with java 11 and the bundled maven from intellij idea. I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] error: Couldn't find type javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped. Are you missing a dependency on your classpath?
[ERROR] error: Couldn't find type javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped. Are you missing a dependency on your classpath?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project dzf-api: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
```

I am not interested to add the dependency that could resolve this issue. To the contrary, i want to find the line of code that produces this error and replace it with `jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` . When i search through my code I replaced all of the javax packages with jakarta packages. It does not find any anymore. Yet the compiler still complains. I need to find the classes that fail to compile, but maven does not indicate which ones fail to compile. Not even when I run with -e .  How can I find these classes? I added :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.dpf.gro</groupId>
  <artifactId>dzf-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.25-b26d0d6</version>
  <properties>
    <!-- Quarkus defined properties -->
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.0.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <!-- / -->
    
    <neo4j-ogm.version>3.2.30</neo4j-ogm.version>
    <neo4j-cypher-dsl.version>2022.1.0</neo4j-cypher-dsl.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
      target/jacoco-report/jacoco.xml
    </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    <!-- / -->
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-neo4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
          <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <version>1.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
      <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-dsl</artifactId>
      <version>${neo4j-cypher-dsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.22.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.20</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
      <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-keycloak-server</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>
                      ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                    </native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
                    </java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-ecosystem-release</id>
      <url>https://devops.dpz.gpo.de/nexus/repository/maven-ecosystem</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>maven-ecosystem-snapshot</id>
      <url>https://devops.dpz.gpo.de/nexus/repository/maven-ecosystem-snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-ecosystem-snapshot</id>
      <url>https://devops.dpz.gpo.de/nexus/repository/maven-ecosystem-snapshot</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried Maven verbose mode? `mvn –X ...`

Comment: yes I have. It doesn't show the classes. Only that it's compiling 74 files and [DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution

Comment: Maybe it is coming from a jar?

Comment: Please add your complete pom to the question.

Comment: how could i find it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated neo4j-ogm and neo4j from quarkiverse. Then the error disappeared.